# provide a SPOSiteDesign from XML instead of JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, xml, pnp, pnp-provision

Is there a way to provide a modern ui site template based on an XML file?
This doesn't seem to work.

```
$site_script = Get-Content -Path "./siteTemplate1.xml" -Raw
$SiteScript = Add-SPOSiteScript  -Title "siteTemplate XML"  -Content $site_script  -Description "siteTemplate1 XML" 
Add-SPOSiteDesign  -Title "siteTemplate XML"  -WebTemplate "64"  -SiteScripts $SiteScript.Id  -Description "siteTemplate1 XML"
```

I tried different ways with PnP-provisioning but making an JSONfile from scratch is just a real pain in the a .. arm.

Some sitetemplates need managed metadata column and connected to a specific hubsite... others sitetemplates need different coloring, ...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are stuck with using JSON I'm afraid.

Have you tried using e.g. this tool to get a start on the JSON? https://www.sitedesigner.io/#/ so that you do not have to start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to see this:

```
$adminSiteUrl = “https://mytenant-admin.sharepoint.com”

$siteUrl = “https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename”

$relativeListUrls = “/lists/listname”, “/lists/listname-2”, “/lists/listname-3”

Connect-SPOService $adminSiteUrl

Get-SPOSiteScriptFromWeb –WebUrl $siteUrl -IncludeTheme -IncludeBranding -IncludeSiteExternalSharingCapability –IncludeRegionalSettings -IncludeLinksToExportedItems –IncludedLists $relativeListUrls | clip
```

**Reference**: [site-template-automate-creation-of-multiple-department-sites](https://meshintranet.com/blog/site-template-automate-creation-of-multiple-department-sites/)